# Webpack not creating the HTML file it used to create

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, webpack

I was building a nodejs app (typescript, react, webpack) and the build was working fine. I.e. I got in the output what I expected. A HTML file, with the bundle file I expected.

Suddenly, without any change in my code, webpack is only generating a the bundle javascript file (as usual) but the HTML file is gone, i.e it does not generate any more.
Here my webpack config file:

```
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/index.tsx"),
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.js']
  },
  output: {
    // options related to how webpack emits results
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.tsx$|.js$/, 
        loader: "ts-loader" ,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src")
      },
    ]
  }
}

module.exports = config;
```

Any clue why my HTML file is not generated anymore and how I can recover it? Thank you!

Comment: Webpack config is fine. Give us at least any way to reproduce your problem.

Comment: What if you add a filename property in your output ? 
Like this `filename: "<output-file>.js".

Comment: @rach8garg no difference. Still no HTML file generated.

Comment: what is your webpack version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the HTML was actually never created. So the question is obsolete.

I was confused because before there used to be an HTML in the output. But it was not generated by webpack (it came from Typescript script)

Answer (score 1):

As I know Webpack by default outputs `main.js` if you do not specify output filename configuration like this code. Try this code:

```
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/index.tsx"),
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.js']
  },
  output: {
    // options related to how webpack emits results
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist"),
    filename: 'my-first-webpack.bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx$/, 
        loader: "ts-loader" ,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src")
      },
    ]
  }
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: I mean, the problem is where is the HTML !? i.e. .html file

Comment: Hi Jose, did you specify output file name in your webpack config file ?

Comment: @Sedar yes it is specified.